# ASP.NET Browser Caps update

Tags: asp.net, .net, gac, browsercaps

I'm trying to update the browser caps using the ".browser" files (browserCaps section of the web.config is deprecated in .NET framework 2.0). So far, I found this project on CodePlex that provides updated files:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420

From the Visual Studio 2008 command promt, I ran the command "aspnet_regbrowsers -i" wich creates an assembly (**ASP.BrowserCapsFactory.dll**) and installs it in the GAC.

So far so good, the updated definitions take effect in my asp.net application.

The question is, is it possible tu use that assembly **outside the GAC**, like add it as reference in a Web application (I tried it and unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't work)?

I'm aware of the "App_Browser" folder solution, but I'm looking for a solution that will ensure the same browsers definitions for several web application without having to put an assembly in the GAC.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASP.NET 4 White paper](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429259)

According to ASP.NET 4 whitepaper, you can manage browser capabilities within your code by extending the ASP.NET Browser capabilities or totally replace it. So far, it's the best you could do instead of using the aspnet_regbrowsers

Comment: Wish I had this option when I was working on that project. For anyone using a newer version of the framework, this might definitely be a possibility.